# Dealing with Flagging Spam posts

Tags: discussion

First off, I want to thank the community for all the Spam flags they have submitted! Bravo!

However, there is an issue that we are slowly, one-by-one addressing, in regards to the spam posts: **People are editing them after flagging them**. This is a [bad idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited), for a couple reasons:

- It invalidates the Spam flag (requiring a mod to intervene).
- When the mod intervenes, we have to click through the question, find the answer (if applicable), then go through the Editing History, then determine from there if it's spammy or not before taking action.

This is not to say we don't want users flagging posts; that's part of your job. What we don't want though is users replacing websites or the spammy parts with **SPAM! DO NOT CLICK!** or other similar messages. We would like to request users simply Flag the post, leave a comment to the poster or other users that it's very spammy, and wait. With 6 Spam-Flag votes from regular users, the post disappears, without needing a Mod to intervene.

If you have any questions regarding this, please come hang out in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing), or post a comment here, or even start a new thread on the meta

Comment: I want to also add that, on Workplace SE, some users will post a link to the spam post in [chat] to draw attention. This can help get those 6 spam flags needed for the system to automatically take action. What's more, it helps others get their flagging badges. :)

Comment: ...also, editing the spam bumps it to the top of the activity page drawing more attention to it — which is exactly what a spammer wants (more attention/eyeballs). It is most effective when this stuff just disappears quietly without fanfare or any indication that people noticed it at all. It makes you a less desirable target for continued spam activity.